# ZF2 load sidebar data every time phtml is loaded

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I'm working on a project using zf2 + the doctrine orm module. In `layout.phtml` I've loaded a partial sidebar phtml for loading side bar news.

I want to know about best coding solutions to load news for that sidebar.phtml. Whether the query for that news list should be in module.php. How can I pass it to viewmodel. Or any other solution for loading partial views data in module.php.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice description on how to create an own view helper and also discussing pros and cons of other solutions:

http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/